# Complex Numbers - show that $z^3 + w^3$ is not purely imaginary

Tags: complex-numbers

Given $z$ and $w$ complex numbers such that $z^2 + w^2 = \exp(i \cos (w))+\exp(i\cos (z))$. Show that $z^3 + w^3$ is not purely imaginary.

A friend give me this question but I can not do it. I was thinking in the equation $\exp(ix) = \cos x + i \sin x$, but I do not have succeed.

Someone could give me a tip?

Comment: We can prove using analytic geometry that if your friend's statement is true, then the set of all $z^3 + w^3$ for $(z,w)$ such that $z^2 + w^2 = \exp(i\cos(z)) + \exp(i\cos(w))$ is finite, which looks very surprising. Are you sure it is true ?

Comment: HINT.- $$z=x+iy\Rightarrow \cos(z)=\cos(x)\cosh(y)+i\sin(x)\sinh(y)\equiv A+iB$$   
$$\cos(\cos(z))=\cos(A)\cosh(B)+i\sin(A)\sinh(B)$$ Besides, for all $z$, $$(\cosh(z))^2-(\sinh(z))^2=1$$ It remains some transpiration. It would be better, if the statement is false, try to find out a counterexample.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what is meant by "purely imaginary" here, Is the claim that **for any** solution $z, w$, $z^3 + w^3$ will have a non-zero real component? Or is it that there is **at least one** solution which has a non-zero real component?